# An example of Gorenstein ring which is not local regular.

Tags: commutative-algebra, regular-rings

I have to find an example of Gorenstein ring which is not local regular.

I take $A=K[|X,Y|]/(XY)$.

This is a local ring. As $XY\in (X,Y)^2$ it results that $A$ is not regular.

$K[|X,Y|]$ is Cohen-Macaulay $\Rightarrow$ $K[|X,Y|]$ is Gorenstein and $XY$ is a nonzero divisor on $K[|X,Y|]$ $\Rightarrow$ $A$ is Gorenstein.

Is it right?

Comment: @user26857 If $(A,m)$ is a local noetherian ring and $x\in m$ then ($A$ is Gorenstein $\Leftrightarrow$ $A/xA$ is Gorenstein).

Comment: @user26857 I need ''$\Rightarrow$''.

Comment: @user26857 You have right! But $X\cdot Y$ is a nonzero divisor in $K[|X,Y|]$.

Comment: Cohen-Macaulay doesn't imply Gorenstein. But obviously $K[[X,Y]]$ is more than Cohen-Macaulay, it's regular.

Comment: Another example which is an integral domain is the following: $R=K[[T^2,T^3]]$. In order to prove that $R$ is Gorenstein, but not regular look at $R/(T^2)$.

Comment: @user26857 Is obviously by definition that  $K [|X,Y|] $ is Gorenstein?

Comment: @user26857 Regular$\Rightarrow$ Gorenstein $\Rightarrow$ Cohen-Macaulay?

Comment: @PregatireMatematica Of course.

Comment: @user26857 What's a slick way to see $K[[T^2, T^3]]$ is Gorenstein? The wiki, for example, lists a lot of homological conditions that I'm not handy with. Any intuition is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: @rschwieb I'd use that a local ring is Gorenstein iff it is Cohen-Macaulay of type one. It's obvious that $R$ is Cohen-Macaulay, $T^2$ is regular on $R$, and the type is dimension (as $K$-vector space) of the socle of $R/(T^2)$, that is, one.